# Is there any downside to buying the Apple TV 3rd generation rather than the 3rd Generation Rev A?

Tags: hardware, appletv, television

The 3rd generation Apple TV apparently comes in two versions:

- 3rd generation (A1427, model MD199LL/A)
- 3rd generation *Rev A* (A1469, *also* model MD199LL/A)

According to the [Apple TV article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_TV#Technical_specifications) these models are identical except for some internal architectural changes which make the Rev A model consume less power.

I'm seeing some prices for the original model A1427 about 25% cheaper than the A1469 model.  Is there any reason to not get the cheaper device?  For example do I risk potential lack of future software support for the older model? E.g. is it conceivable that Apple could release a software version that runs on the A1469 but doesn't run on the A1427?

Answer (score 2):

Rev A can perform peer-to-peer Airplay wireless streaming. Source: http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT4437